# How to add json array to object in existing array?

Tags: arrays

I have an object `myObj.employees` which looks like this:

`{"employees":[{"key":1419,"rankid":8,"label":"bob (47)","exclude":false,"color":"#ffffff","textColor":"#330000","active_events":[]},{"key":1420,"rankid":8,"label":"john (48)","exclude":false,"color":"#ffffff","textColor":"#330000","active_events":[]}]}`

how do I add items to `active_events` for `key = 1419` ?

Comment: What language are you working in? Please add an appropriate tag.

Comment: Does the `myObj.employees` object then contain a property called `employees`, so that it would need to be accessed as `myObj.employees.employees`, or does `myObj` directly contain the `employees` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the 1419 entry:

```
const entry = myObj.employees.find(obj => obj.key === 1419);
```

Add entries to active events:

```
entry.active_events.push("more item");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in Javascript you can use the `.forEach` function to iterate over the `employees` array in a brute force manner.

```
myObj.employees.forEach(function(e) {
  if (e.key === 1419) {
    e.active_events.push("waffles")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myObj.employees["employees"][0]["active_events"].append("new event")
```

unless the object you showed was really just myObj in which case the answer (in python) would be:

myObj["employees"][0]["active_events"].append("new event")

let's break this down.

1. We take your object (myObj.employees) which gives us a dictionary with one key value pair.
2. We dive into ["employees"] to access the  employee list.
3. You want to edit the [0] index employee
4. You want to edit the ["active_events"] value
5. You want to append / edit the list. I think you can take it from here.

As others have show if you do not know the index of the employee you want to edit, which you probably won't, then you'll need to loop through and look for it.

```
for i, employee in enumerate(myObj["employees"]):
    if employee["key"] == 1419:
        myObj["employees"][i]["active_events"].append('new event')
```